# Is saying each pt of a topo. manifold has nbhd homeomorphic to R^n the same thing as saying there is a local coordinate system at each point?

Tags: differential-geometry

Is saying each point of a topological manifold has a neighborhood homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^{n}$ the same thing as saying there is a local coordinate system at each point?

I'm not really sure what I mean by coordinate system. It's just a term I have heard used. If someone could define that at the same time that would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is true by definition:

A topological space $M$ is said to be locally Euclidean of dimension $n$ if each point $x \in M$ has a neighbourhood $U$ homeomorphic to an open subset $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. A homeomorphism of this sort is by definition a coordinate chart.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you mean that each point has a neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.  A local coordinate system about a point is basically a choice of homeomorphism from a neighborhood of that point to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: So then the answer is yes?

Comment: I don't think the question is really well defined, but the idea of a manifold is that you can find local coordinates at each point.

Answer (score -1):

generally when imposing coordinate systems there is the additional condition that they are compatible. Thus if two neighbourhood's intersect then the intersection the associated two homeomorphisms yield a map between two subsets of $R^n.$ This map must also be a homeomorphism for a coordinate system.

Comment: I believe that the compatibility condition is automatically satisfied in the continuous category, unless I'm not mistaken.  In the smooth category it is a necessary axiom.

Comment: I agree. If you check out Lee's topological manifolds text there is no requirement for "compatibility" that needs to be imposed (p. 38).